# Typescript make parameters depend on a parameter that's a union of literals

Tags: typescript

There a few other questions about this, but I can't find one for this exact use case.

I have a method signature like this:

```js
function respondToAction(action: "create" | "update" | "delete", old: Record<string, any> | undefined, change: Record<string, any> | undefined)
```

I want to express the typings in a way that if `action === "create"`, old is inferred as undefined, if `action === update`, both old and change are defined, and if `action === delete`, then change is undefined.

Is there a way I can express this?

edit: I just tried this:

```js
type Action = "create" | "update" | "delete";
type Function =
 <A extends Action>(action: A,
  old: A extends "create" ? undefined : Fields,
  change: A extends "create" | "update" ? Fields : undefined
) => void
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Within the function, I tried to branch on `action`, and even if I have a `if(action === "create") { ... }` it doesn't properly infer change as defined within the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give `respondToAction` a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [rest tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), and immediately [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into the three variables named `action`, `old`, and `change`:

```
type Data = Record<string, any>;

function respondToAction(...[action, old, change]:
    [action: "create", old: undefined, change: Data] |
    [action: "update", old: Data, change: Data] |
    [action: "delete", old: Data, change?: undefined]
) { /* impl */ }
```

You can see that this behaves as desired from the caller's side.  It behaves similarly to overloads, but you have only one actual call signature:

```
respondToAction("create", undefined, { a: 1, b: 2 });  // okay
respondToAction("update", { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 3 }); // okay
respondToAction("delete", { a: 1, b: 3 }); // okay
respondToAction("delete", undefined, { a: 1, b: 2 });  // error
respondToAction("create", { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 3 }); // error
respondToAction("update", { a: 1, b: 3 }); // error
```

And since TypeScript 4.6 and above supports [control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions), you can switch on `action` in the implementation and the compiler will automatically narrow `old` and `change` accordingly:

```
function respondToAction(...[action, old, change]:
    [action: "create", old: undefined, change: Data] |
    [action: "update", old: Data, change: Data] |
    [action: "delete", old: Data, change?: undefined]
) {

    old.testProp; // compiler error, possibly undefined
    change.testProp; // compiler error, possibly undefined

    if (action !== "create") {
        old.testProp // okay, old is known to be defined
    }
    if (action !== "delete") {
        change.testProp // okay, change is known to be defined    
    }
    
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGijkpAD4BuAKHYDMBXSzYOWyUouCMTDD8AFWwBBAUMoAKAHTqA2nEXD62ADb56mABaNqEALoAudlHtQtOytagAiTGIQQ3ew6758CC4qCCMoU3MIV3hESygAHzsHJ0FhVzceMHxvXygDfBiEOGMzGmjYYvikh0dtNJd3IP0IYB8-QsrEUqiAfgDKIJDKMMt2AEooAG9OWrIQaeTa+wLVNtIABVxsMFYoAHp9iOwAWzByFtwoCFxt3HpJYmJyACN9BcDg0Pwl5cjytbiYBbHZ7Q7HM4XG7XW54B7YJ6vd5QT7DMK-AC+EQQpigyhuuEmM2WDhwlGIBggqn02Go+Nu4w4tQxv3IXDx9SUUAAhMhUB4vG03ETfrVVutgdswAcjtgANZwEAdKDkYhQOWUbAAdxEwGwUBe0CG30xrPZyk5wh5fKaEBaQpFJPs-wsgM2Upl+QVSoiZQsKrVGu1uv1hqgxpG+Fqps4LPYYgkUlkCgaygFEFy9FR33oUwYrgAjPQXq4AExQDGM+zg+WK+PiSSDZPONNZHJC3P5qBFg1liuduCF4uuADMFarNe99cTTfkLbczVa7WmXZ7JagY8rYNlU-Y80WtQTjZkc9TC7tS7y2cjA6Hvag5a31aOBLwvyPSdPSjTngzHZXg7dsOD79gBd7rpuE4vrCuDvg2n4pt+mTZJmYFAfekHbjCdzsFimA4iYeIEo6pLCBSLTUrS9KErh7BAA)

Comment: This is pretty cool! It does what I was looking for, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [functions overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Example:

```
function respondToAction(action: "create"): void;
function respondToAction(action: "delete", old: Record<string, any>): void;
function respondToAction(action: "update", old: Record<string, any>, change: Record<string, any>): void;
function respondToAction(action: "create" | "update" | "delete", old?: Record<string, any>, change?: Record<string, any>): void {
    // TODO
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYGcAOCAmAVOAQWnjAAoBDEhALkQCII0KpV6BKOgNzhhwG4AUKEiwEKDNjD4i1clTFg69HKgA2qVvQA0iOGpx0ASqghxkOADzooyGGADmuimACeAPk6IefISLkSWLgExIqUcsogmDgsbLr6hogmZhbWtvZOiC4euhAAFi4OqMam5lY2do7Obp7cvALC4AFoQdIhcuGKykyosfSIAD4MUTFagwyqGlrxBgD8JSnl6VVZNbkFjqjzSaWpFRnVHl4%20OIgA3oKIV4gA9DeIeADyACKPggC%20goItUjKhpGQAOQ9WKA9hCH7BWRhQGTTSoQG6M7vcHfSRQ-4IIEjUFI9548FAA)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to do it without overloads-- I want to have a single function that has logic that branches conditionally on action's value within the function. See my edit for an example that I tried.